# I want to add an ean 13 barcode scanner to my application but it wont work on swift playgrounds for Ipad

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am trying to add an scanner to my application but everytime when I run the application it sais that there is a problem in my code and that I have to try again
The code what I have is from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-barcode, I tried to paste it on to an blank document and a Xcode-playground document but both of them didn’t work.[image: This is the response after running the code Down bellow]

```
Import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.ean8, .ean13, .pdf417]
    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

    captureSession.startRunning()
}

func failed() {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
    present(ac, animated: true)
    captureSession = nil
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()
    }
}

func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
        guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        found(code: stringValue)
    }

    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func found(code: String) {
    print(code)
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

}

Comment: What is the thing that you refer to as 'swift playgrounds'?

Comment: The app that u use to make ios apps on the ipad

Comment: It goes with `UIViewController`?  `viewDidLoad` without importing PlaygoundSupport?